# Liferay 7 AngularJS and multiple portlet

Tags: angularjs, liferay, bootstrapping, liferay-7

I have got few questions about this topic. I'm a Angular developer but new in Liferay (The version is 7). I tried to create a portlet using AngularJs. The portlet works well. After that, i tried to create, in the same project, another portlet in AngularJs and put it on the same page. I used the same structure of the first one and it worked well.
Now the google chrome console returns this warning:

> WARNING: Tried to load AngularJS more than once

My question is:
Is it correct use multiple portlet made in Angular on the same page with the same structure for the bootstrapping?
And that's the code I use to do it in the view.jsp file (of the first working portlet):

```
<%@ include file="/init.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<div id="main" ng-controller="MainController" ng-cloak>
    <div>{{helloWorld}}</div>       
</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap', 'myApp.MainController']);

myApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.liferay = {
        token: Liferay.authToken,
        companyId: Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getCompanyId(),
        loggedIn: Liferay.ThemeDisplay.isSignedIn()
    }; 
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("main"), ['myApp']);
</script>
```

The same code is on the second portlet. Is that the correct way? Thank you in advance

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. Limit the question to a **specific problem** with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @georgeawg I changed the question with just one

Comment: Is there an `ng-app` directive in the include file? If so it needs to be removed if you intend to do a manual bootstrap.

Comment: Nope. There is not ng-app directive.. but i noticed that i can avoid to import the angulars.js script in every portlet. I can just put the js in one of them. But of course i need to do the bootstrap manually for each portlet. In this way i haven't got the WARNING